# How to Group PHP Array Based On Year with Nested Array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

My Current PHP Array Outputs like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2015
            [month] => November
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2015
            [month] => October
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2015
            [month] => September
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2015
            [month] => August
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2015
            [month] => July
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2015
            [month] => June
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2015
            [month] => May
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2015
            [month] => April
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2015
            [month] => March
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2015
            [month] => February
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2015
            [month] => January
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2014
            [month] => December
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2014
            [month] => November
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2014
            [month] => October
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2014
            [month] => September
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2014
            [month] => August
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2014
            [month] => July
        )

)
```

I want to sort the above Array and group them based on the Year. The Array I want to convert the above is to get like this:

```
Array (

[0] => Array 
    (
        [yearGroup] => “2015”
        [dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [year] => 2015
                            [month] => November
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [year] => 2015
                            [month] => October
                        )
                    …etc..etc…

                )
    )

[1] => Array
        (
            [yearGroup] => 2014
            [dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [year] => 2014
                            [month] => December
                        )
                [1] => Array
                        (
                            [year] => 2014
                            [month] => November
                        )
                    …etc..etc…

                )
        )

)
```

This is the code I have tried so far:

```
    $calendar = // ..... The Array Above .....; 

    $sidebarCalendar = array();
    $currentYear = '';
    $i = 0;

    foreach ($calendar as $date) {
      if ($currentYear != $date['year']) {
          $currentYear = $date['year'];
          $i++;
          $tempYearDates = array();
          $j = 0;
          $tempYearDates[$j] = array(
            'year'  => $date['year'],
            'month' => $date['month']
          );
          $j++;
          // Add to Array
          $sidebarCalendar[$i] = array (
            'yearGroup' => $date['year'],
            'dates'     => $tempYearDates
          );
      }
      else {
          $tempYearDates = array(
            'year'  => $date['year'],
            'month' => $date['month']
          );
          // Locate the Array Tree
          $currentParent = $sidebarCalendar[$i];
          $currentArray = $currentParent['dates'];
          $currentArray[$j] = $tempYearDates;
          $j++;
      }
    }
```

But the above outputs incomplete array like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [yearGroup] => 2015
            [dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [year] => 2015
                            [month] => November
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [yearGroup] => 2014
            [dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [year] => 2014
                            [month] => December
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Can someone point out what I have got wrong here please? If there is a better way to do the same instead of the above method, please do guide me there please…

Comment: You're not adding anything to `$sidebarCalender` in your else which I assume is what's holding your new array structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use some of the builtin PHP's array functions to solve this issue. First thing you want to do is get all the unique years in that array, so you could do:

```
$years = array_unique(array_map(function($item) { return $item['year']; }, $calendar));
```

Here, I've used `array_map` to get an array containing only the `year` property for each item, and fed it to the `array_unique` function to get only unique values.

Next thing you could do is iterate through all the years, and populate another array, something like this:

```
$grouped = [];
foreach($years as $year) {
    $grouped[$year] = array_filter($calendar, function($item) use ($year) { return $item['year'] === $year; });
}
```

This way you'll get a key for each year in the `grouped` variable, and each key will contain a subarray composed only of the elements of calendar satisfying the `array_filter` condition.

I'm sure there are better / more optimized ways of doing this (maybe using `array_walk` or `array_reduce`?) and I encourage you to find those! Still, remember that there are many array functions builtin in PHP, read their documentation and learn when to use them, they'll be of great help!

Edit: I realize that the output of my solution is not exactly what you're expecting, but it's very easily adaptable. I myself prefer using keyed arrays (maps?) whenever possible in place of regular arrays with properties, but to each their own!

```
$grouped = [];
foreach($years as $year) {
    $grouped[] = [
         'yearGroup' => $year,
         'dates' => array_filter($calendar, function($item) use ($year) { return $item['year'] === $year; })
    ];
}
```

Edit 2: Sometimes I forget how to PHP.

Comment: Thank you @juandemarco I will give that a try and will post back an update.

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated my answer with a similar solution that better reflects the output you were expecting.

Comment: It certainly does look a lot simpler than what I have been trying. :)

Comment: That's the thing, when you end up writing code that has many steps and maybe temporary variables and whatnot, there usually is a simpler way. You just need to know where to look - usually chunking the code into smaller (reusable!) functions goes a long way!

Comment: Just now I added this to my app and it works perfectly. I never thought this was doable so easily. You're right, breaking down the steps into smaller functions makes it hellova lot easier. Compared to your simple solution, mine looked like a program from 1960s. Thank you so much!

Comment: This is what I love about SO, Good thing is: I get to learn new things, Bad Thing is: it reminds me of how much more there is to learn :)

Comment: I read somewhere that if you look back at your code six months after writing it and don't see a problem, you are the problem. We all have much more to learn, always. It's our job to never stop improving! Happy to help mate ;)